# Tabulate - How to Cascade tables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to display two tables next to another using tabulate.

My approach:

```
test_table1 = tabulate([['Alice', 24], ['Bob', 19]])
test_table2 = tabulate([['Hans', 45], ['John', 38]])
master_headers = ["table1", "table2"]
master_table = tabulate([[test_table1, test_table2]],
                        master_headers, tablefmt="simple")
print(master_table)
```

But this results in both tables being displayed in the column of table1.

See:
[image]

**Question:** How can i cascade tables in python, preferably using tabulate(or a similar library)?

Thanks in advance!

Muff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know if this is the best choice that you get, but that's what i came up with

```
test_table1 = str(tabulate([['Alice', 24], ['Bob', 19]])).splitlines()
test_table2 = str(tabulate([['Hans', 45], ['John', 38]])).splitlines()
master_headers = ["table1", "table2"]
master_table = tabulate([list(item) for item in zip(test_table1,test_table2)],
                        master_headers, tablefmt="simple")
print(master_table)
```

Output:

```
table1     table2
---------  --------
-----  --  ----  --
Alice  24  Hans  45
Bob    19  John  38
-----  --  ----  --
```

**Explanation**:

The purpose was to pass array of strings to *master_table*'s `tabulate`, like it was done with *test_table1* and *test_table2*

With `.splitlines()`

```
>>>str(tabulate([['Alice', 24], ['Bob', 19]]))
>>>'-----  --\nAlice  24\nBob    19\n-----  --'
>>>str(tabulate([['Alice', 24], ['Bob', 19]])).splitlines()
>>>['-----  --', 'Alice  24', 'Bob    19', '-----  --']
```

So we had `['-----  --', 'Alice  24', 'Bob    19', '-----  --']` and `['----  --', 'Hans  45', 'John  38', '----  --']`, but we can't pass them that way, because output would be quite strange:

```
table1     table2
---------  ---------  ---------  ---------
-----  --  Alice  24  Bob    19  -----  --
----  --   Hans  45   John  38   ----  --
```

So we needed to `zip` those lists, and convert values to `list`, because `zip` return `list` of `tuple` objects, that's what happened here:

```
>>>[list(item) for item in zip(test_table1,test_table2)]
>>>[['-----  --', '----  --'],
   ['Alice  24', 'Hans  45'],
   ['Bob    19', 'John  38'],
   ['-----  --', '----  --']]
```

And that is the way how `tabulate` easily will get data and put as you desired.